# Optimization of a large array sum (multi-threaded)

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I want to optimize the sum of a really big array and in order to do that I have wrote a multi-threaded code. The problem is that with this code I'm getting better timing results using only one thread instead of 2 or 3 or 4 threads...

Can someone explain me why this happens?
(Also I've only started coding in C++ this semester, until then I only knew C, so I'm sorry for possible dumb mistakes)

*This is the thread code*

```
    *localSum = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stop; i++)
            *localSum += v[i];
```

*Main process code*

```
    int numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int N = 100000000;

    // create the input vector v and put some values in v
    vector<double> v(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            v[i] = i;

    // this vector will contain the partial sum for each thread
    vector<double> localSum(numThreads, 0);

    // create threads. Each thread will compute part of the sum and store
    // its result in localSum[threadID] (threadID = 0, 1, ... numThread-1)
    startChrono();
    vector<thread> myThreads(numThreads);

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
            int start = i * v.size() / numThreads;
            myThreads[i] = thread(threadsum, i, numThreads, &v[start], &localSum[i],v.size()/numThreads);
    }


    for_each(myThreads.begin(), myThreads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

    // calculate global sum
    double globalSum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            globalSum += localSum[i];

    cout.precision(12);
    cout << "Sum = " << globalSum << endl;
    cout << "Runtime: " << stopChrono() << endl;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: Good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your particular problem, you'd have to extract a [mcve]. Abbreviated code is often not suitable for a real analysis which then leads to guessing. Also, an MCVE forces you to focus on the problem yourself first.

Comment: Since you aren't doing any significant calculations you will be memory access time bound. Using separate threads doesn't change that on normal architectures and just adds the additional thread creation/destruction overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things:

1- The array just isn't big enough. Vectorized streaming add will be really hard to beat. You need a more complex function than add to really see results. Or a very large array.

2- Related, the overhead of all the thread creation and joining is going to swamp any performance gains from the threading. Adding is really fast, and you can easily saturate the CPU's functional units. for the thread to help it can't even be a hyperthread on the same core, it would need to be on a different core entirely (as the hyperthreads would both compete for the floating point units).

To test this, you can try to create all the treads before you start the timer and stop them all after you stop the timer (have them set a done flag instead of waiting on the join).

3- All your localsum variables are sharing the same cache line. Better would be to make the localsum variable on the stack and put the result into the array instead of adding directly into the array: https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/false-sharing.html

If for some reason, you need to keep the sum observable to others in that array, pad the localsum vector entries like this so they don't share the same cache line:

```
struct localsumentry {
  double sum;
  char pad[56];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
The 3rd point that you wrote was definitely what I was looking for and really helped getting better results (10+ times better results considering speedup).